# On a certain property of some Groups' subsets

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, soft-question

I have noticed several instances of the following property:

> $S \subset G$ is a subset of a group $(G, \cdot)$ for which holds   $\forall s, s' \in S,\ \ s \cdot s' \notin S$

Some notable examples are:

- The odd integers: $\lbrace n \in \mathbb{Z}\ \vert\ n \equiv 1 \mod 2 \rbrace \subset (\mathbb{Z}, +)$
- The purely imaginary numbers: $\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C}_{\neq 0} \rbrace  \ \vert\ \Re(z) = 0 \rbrace \subset (\mathbb{C}_{\neq 0}, \times)$
- The set of odd permutations on $n$ letters: $S_n \setminus A_n \subset S_n$
- The set of [$n\times n$ Anti-diagonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-diagonal_matrix) $\subset GL_n(\mathbb{R})$

I already found this fact rather amusing on its own but I was wondering whether there was something more to it, maybe a more general setting in which all these examples could fit together without it seeming like a mere coincidence.

My question is: has this "*anti-closure*" property has been studied before and if there are some interesting results about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any non-trivial coset of a subgroup has this property.
This explains the odd integers example and the odd permutations.

Comment: Note that it is much easier for a "small" subset to have this property. In fact, you'd expect a random small subset to have this property. On the other hand, it is much harder for a large subset to have this property. Your first and third are "large" subsets ("half" the elements, by some measure) and so it not surprising that they must have some special structure to have this property.